# c# - disable events during MouseDoubleClick

Tags: c#, events

Is it possible to disable other MouseEvent during a MouseDoubleClick event?
I've registered multiple events on a label but i want MouseDoubleClick is prioritary and block all other MouseEvent (es. MouseDown or MuoseMove). Then, after the DoubleClickHandler is finished i want to reactivate them.

Comment: You could implement a timer system to see if it was a double click or not. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx) has a page on seperating the two

Answer (score 2):

You can create a flag to store your different states in order for your methods to know what they have to know.

A simple approach will be something like:

```
bool dblClickDone = false;

void DoubleClickHandler(...) 
{
    //...
    dblClickDone = true;
}

void MouseDownHandler(...) 
{
    if (dblClickDone) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but the `MouseDoubleClick` event is 7th out of 8 events in a chain (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx). How would the system know if it was a double click and not just a normal click such that the `dblClickDone` variable can be set retroactively?

Comment: @keyboardP The framework handles the event firing for you. `The MouseDoubleClick event occurs when the user depresses a mouse button twice in quick succession when the cursor is over the control`

Comment: But I thought OP was asking how to detect a double click prior to a single click/mouse move event. A single click event would still be raised at this stage so their single click event handler would fire too which is what, I *think*, OP wants to avoid (I could be wrong). In your example, `MouseDownHandler` would fire first so `dblClickDone` would be false the first time which means the chain would be out of sync by one

Comment: @keyboardP Ok, now I understood you. This solution is not about making the framework not to fire some events. This solution is about controlling the code is going to be executed and under which circumstances inside any event

Comment: I think the issue is what if the user only wants to single click? The `dblClickDone` variable will be false so that block will be skipped. The user would have to double click once to set the variable to true and then single click again to get that action to execute.

Comment: I've already tried solutions with flags but didn't work. keyboardP has got the point: i don't want to fire other events during a DoubleClick.

Comment: then I was going so suggest a new solution, but `x...` did it, [check his/her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38348621/1967056)

Answer (score 1):

Just unregister the events using "-=", example:

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  this.MouseDown -= MethodOnMouseDown;
  this.MouseMove -= MethodOnMouseMove;

  // Do something.....

  this.MouseDown += MethodOnMouseDown;
  this.MouseMove += MethodOnMouseMove;
}
```

Comment: Maybe he/her needs to unregister the event before this event is raised but yeah, that's the idea

Comment: This wouldn't work because the `MouseDown` event is fired before the double click so the detachment would happen after the MouseDown event is called. I've added a comment to the original question which shows a way Microsoft suggest achieving this (essentially a custom timer)

Comment: @keyboardP Maybe you should add it as an answer

Comment: @SysDragon - I will do if OP confirms it's what they were looking for :)

Comment: @keyboardP You don't need to wait. Event if it's not what he/she needs, it may help others

Comment: @SysDragon - True, I've added the answer :)

Comment: It doesn't work..already tried. I was planning to change design and avoid DoubleClick. I inserted a button :)

Comment: It will never work, you cannot use SingleClick and DoubleClick at the same time, you must choose Single or Double, but not both. No one using Single and Double Click at the same time. Sample above is just a sample how to unregister event, do something, and register it again.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests two methods. The one you use will be based on the design of you program. I've copied the code from MSDN below in case the page goes down.

First method is to rollback any changes made that were made in the 'single click' event if the double click event is fired.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MouseRollBackSingleClick
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DoubleClickButton button1;
        private FormBorderStyle initialStyle;

        public Form1()
        {
            initialStyle = this.FormBorderStyle;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
            button1 = new DoubleClickButton();
            button1.Location = new Point (40,40);
            button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
            button1.AutoSize = true;
            this.AllowDrop = true;
            button1.Text = "Click or Double Click";
            button1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(button1_DoubleClick);
            this.Controls.Add(button1);

        }


        // Handle the double click event.
        void button1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the border style back to the initial style.
            this.FormBorderStyle = initialStyle;
            MessageBox.Show("Rolled back single click change.");
        }

        // Handle the click event.
        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }


    }
    public class DoubleClickButton : Button
    {
        public DoubleClickButton() : base()
        {
            // Set the style so a double click event occurs.
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | 
                ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The second method is to create a timer which triggers when the single click is performed. If a double click is not followed within the timer limit, it's assumed the user wants to perform a single click and that action is taken, otherwise the double click action is taken.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SingleVersusDoubleClick
{
    class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Rectangle hitTestRectangle = new Rectangle();
        private Rectangle doubleClickRectangle = new Rectangle();
        private TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        private Timer doubleClickTimer = new Timer();
        private ProgressBar doubleClickBar = new ProgressBar();
        private Label label1 = new Label();
        private Label label2 = new Label();
        private bool isFirstClick = true;
        private bool isDoubleClick = false;
        private int milliseconds = 0;

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            label1.Location = new Point(30, 5);
            label1.Size = new Size(100, 15);
            label1.Text = "Hit test rectangle:";

            label2.Location = new Point(30, 70);
            label2.Size = new Size(100, 15);
            label2.Text = "Double click timer:";

            hitTestRectangle.Location = new Point(30, 20);
            hitTestRectangle.Size = new Size(100, 40);

            doubleClickTimer.Interval = 100;
            doubleClickTimer.Tick +=
                new EventHandler(doubleClickTimer_Tick);

            doubleClickBar.Location = new Point(30, 85);
            doubleClickBar.Minimum = 0;
            doubleClickBar.Maximum = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;

            textBox1.Location = new Point(30, 120);
            textBox1.Size = new Size(200, 100);
            textBox1.AutoSize = false;
            textBox1.Multiline = true;

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
            this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { doubleClickBar, textBox1, 
                label1, label2 });
        }

        // Detect a valid single click or double click.
        void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verify that the mouse click is in the main hit
            // test rectangle.
            if (!hitTestRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                return;
            }

            // This is the first mouse click.
            if (isFirstClick)
            {
                isFirstClick = false;

                // Determine the location and size of the double click 
                // rectangle area to draw around the cursor point.
                doubleClickRectangle = new Rectangle(
                    e.X - (SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width / 2),
                    e.Y - (SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height / 2),
                    SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width,
                    SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height);
                Invalidate();

                // Start the double click timer.
                doubleClickTimer.Start();
            }

            // This is the second mouse click.
            else
            {
                // Verify that the mouse click is within the double click
                // rectangle and is within the system-defined double 
                // click period.
                if (doubleClickRectangle.Contains(e.Location) &&
                    milliseconds < SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
                {
                    isDoubleClick = true;
                }
            }
        }

        void doubleClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            milliseconds += 100;
            doubleClickBar.Increment(100);

            // The timer has reached the double click time limit.
            if (milliseconds >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
            {
                doubleClickTimer.Stop();

                if (isDoubleClick)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText("Perform double click action");
                    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText("Perform single click action");
                    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }

                // Allow the MouseDown event handler to process clicks again.
                isFirstClick = true;
                isDoubleClick = false;
                milliseconds = 0;
                doubleClickBar.Value = 0;
            }
        }

        // Paint the hit test and double click rectangles.
        void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Draw the border of the main hit test rectangle.
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, hitTestRectangle);

            // Fill in the double click rectangle.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, doubleClickRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with having events on double click and mouse up. I've experienced that the mouse up during the double click gets triggered twice during a double click as is reasonable.

What worked best for me was to hide the mouse up behind two levels on when it can be triggered. A bool and a timer with an interval short enough not to be noticeable by the user but longer than the interval between clicks in a double click.

The bool let's call it canMouseUp is true by default. and should be set to false during a double click to ignore the mouse up as the double click is finished.

the mouse up checks for canMouseUp and if it is false then it is set to true, nothing else. If canMouseUp is true then I start the mouseUpTimer.

double click stops the mouseUpTimer, sets canMouseUp to false and does it's own thing.

```
private void MyObject_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!canMouseUp)
            {
                canMouseUp= true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mouseUpTimer.Start();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

private void MyObject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                mouseUpTimer.Stop();
                // Do what DoubleClick is supposed to do
                canMouseUp = false;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
private void mouseUpTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                // Do what Mouse up is supposed to do.
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```